# Typescript version does not update

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am running the following command to update my TypeScript version from 1.8.5 to 2.0.7 :

**npm install -g typescript**

it shows as **-- typescript@2.0.7**

Afterwards, when I am trying to check it manually using : **tsc --version**,
it shows me : **Version 1.8.5**

Please tell me **how to upgrade version of typescript from Version 1.8.5 to 2.0.7**.

Comment: Do you have any other version of typescript installed, like from Visual Studio?  If not, go into the global packages directory and remove everything typescript and reinstall

Comment: Try uninstalling your existing `typescript` package(s) by executing `npm uninstall -g typescript` and then try installing the same like how you tried it eariler.

Comment: Check from which folder `tsc` being executed. Windows: `where tsc`, Unix: `which tsc`. Maybe there is another tsc on your path before npm's.

Comment: Above both sollutions are very helpful for me..thanks!!

Comment: I have run this exe from 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593' and set the environment variable in control panel and restart my computer then i got new version of my typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Down load "TypeScript_Dev12.exe" and run it.

After successfully installing, you will find "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.0" in your system. Copy that path.

Now go to Environment Variables->System Variables->Path, now click on edit. Remove old path of type script and add new path over there.

Now restart your system. You will now find 2.0 as your typescript version.

Answer (score 1):

Megha shah is right, but I think is better to install via npm globally

```
npm install typescript -g
```

and so use the existing C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm.